# Does Sencha Touch, or any other HTML5 javascript framework, allow access to a mobile phone's media library for uploading video to a server?

Tags: html, video, mobile, upload, sencha-touch

I am looking at building an app that can take a video from a person's media library on their mobile phone and upload it to my servers. As far as I can tell, I'd have to build an application for each type of mobile device I want to include. But if new HTML5 protocols let me upload video files through the browser (and can handle the file size), this would be a preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

Web apps don't have access to the media library on a phone. Use phonegap to get access to the users photos - http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html

Comment: Yeah, thanks Joel! I'm familiar with PhoneGap...  Looking for video support, not photo.  I did see they had *capture* capabilities for Android and BB (http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_media_capture_capture.md.html#capture.captureVideo), but I'm looking for grabbing and uploading, not capturing.

Comment: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494789/iPhone:-Camera-API shows how to turn an image into a base64 string. From there you should be able to put that into an AJAX request and send it to your server. Not sure if this will work for video, if it does the base64 sting could be quite large and you may run into javascript string limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using iOS and running the WebApp in iOS' MobileSafari, you have NO access to any system related components, libraries or anything (so no Photos, Videos etc).

And Safari itself does not support file upload. You can add the tag but it will always remain as if had disabled="disabled" attribute.

The only way to access these components is by using a Native code or, like Joel said, PhoneGap since it gives the html pages, access to Native API's through it's JS Framework.

For Android, i have no idea but probably not.